# Queue giving erroneous data

Tags: c++

So I'm attempting to use a queue to parse some input, turning prefix mathematical expressions into infix mathematical expressions with parentheses. For example: +++12 20 3 4 turns into (((12+20)+3)+4). For the most part, my algorithm works, except for one specific thing. When the numbers are greater than 2 digits long, the output becomes strange. I'll give you some examples instead of attempting to explain.

```
Examples: +++12 200 3 4 becomes (((12+3)+3)+4)
+++12 2000 3 4 becomes (((12+20004)+3)+4)
+++12 20005 3 4 becomes (((12+20004)+3)+4)
+++12 20005 3 45 becomes (((12+20004)+3)+45)
+++12 20005 3 456 becomes (((12+20004)+3)+()
```

Hopefully that's enough examples, if you need more, just ask.

I'm using GCC 4.2 in XCode on Mac OSX 10.6.2.

And here is the code that does this wonderful thing:

```
#include "EParse.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


EParse::EParse( char* s )
{
    this->s = s;
    len = strlen( s );
}

void EParse::showParsed()
{
    parse( s, 0, len, new std::queue< char* >(), new std::queue< char >() );
}

void EParse::parse( char* str, int beg, int len, std::queue< char* > *n, std::queue< char > *ex )
{
    //ex is for mathematical expressions (+, -, etc.), n is for numbers
    if( beg == len )
    {
        if( ex->size() > n->size() )
        {
            std::cout << "Malformed expression. Too many mathematical expressions to too few numbers." << std::endl;
            std::cout << ex->size() << " mathematical expressions." << std::endl;
            std::cout << n->size() << " number(s)." << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string *s = new std::string();
            output( n, ex, 0, s );
            std::cout << s->c_str();
            return;
        }
    }

    if( str[ beg ] == ' ' && beg != ( len - 1 ) )
        beg++;
    if( num( str[ beg ] ) )
    {
        std::string *s = new std::string();
        getNum( s, str, beg, len );
        //std::cout << s->c_str() << std::endl;
        n->push( const_cast< char* >( s->c_str() ) );
        delete s;
        parse( str, beg, len, n, ex );
    }
    else if( mathexp( str[ beg ] ) )
    {
        ex->push( str[ beg ] );
        parse( str, beg + 1, len, n, ex );
    }
}

void EParse::getNum( std::string *s, char* str, int &beg, int len )
{
    if( num( str[ beg ] ) )
    {
        char *t = new char[ 1 ];
        t[ 0 ] = str[ beg ];
        s->append( t );
        beg += 1;
        getNum( s, str, beg, len );
    }
}

bool EParse::num( char c )
{
    return c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' ||
    c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9';
}

bool EParse::mathexp( char c )
{
    return c == '+' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%' || c == '-';
}

void EParse::output( std::queue< char* > *n, std::queue< char > *ex, int beg, std::string *str )
{
    if( ex->empty() )
    {
        return;
    }

    char *t = new char[1];
    t[ 0 ] = ex->front();
    ex->pop();
    if( beg == 0 )
    {
        str->insert( 0, "(" );
        str->append( n->front() );
        beg += 1 + strlen( n->front() );
        n->pop();
        str->append( t );
        str->append( n->front() );
        str->append( ")" );
        beg += 2 + strlen( n->front() );
        n->pop();
    }       
    else 
    {
        str->insert( 0, "(" );
        str->insert( beg, t );
        str->insert( beg + 1, n->front() );
        beg += 1 + strlen( n->front() );
        str->insert( beg, ")" );
        n->pop();
        beg++;
    }

    //ex->pop();
    output( n, ex, beg + 1, str );
    //std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

If you need any commenting or explaining of what exactly certain stuff does, please let me know, I will be checking back here fairly often tonight.

Comment: Can you post a few examples of your EParse class in use please? i.e. your main() function, or similar?

Comment: @sgreeve
Check the examples I put at the top of the post. Those are pretty much how I would use the class.
EParse e( "+++12 200 3 4" );
e.showParsed();
That's my main, as an example. All parsing is done in-class before being output, in-class.

As a side note, this class uses purely recursive methods. I wouldn't normally do that, but it's required for the homework.

Comment: Thanks. It's not clear from the examples you posted without going through every line of code that you would just call showParsed(). The clearer you make it, the quicker you're likely to get someone to help!

Comment: -1 You should try to find the problem yourself or at least isolate it somehow. You have posted too much too cryptic code here.

Comment: @Tronic I stepped through the program line by line while debugging, and EVERYTHING works perfectly until I get the front of the queue later during the output() function. getNum goes through the string just fine and gets the numbers just fine, pushing them into the queue perfectly well. I have no idea why it would work perfectly until I'm trying to get my data from the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have the exact answer to your problem, I did notice this:

```
std::string *s = new std::string();
getNum( s, str, beg, len );
//std::cout << s->c_str() << std::endl;
n->push( const_cast< char* >( s->c_str() ) );
delete s;
```

The problem there is you are pushing `s` into the queue and then you are deleting it. The queue, then, will be referencing a string's value that no longer is valid, which could lead to the errors you are describing.

To make life a little easier for you, I would recommend changing your queue type to:

```
std::queue<std::string>
```

Then you can push and pop whole `std::string`s instead of pointers to their data:

```
n->push(s);
```

Note that you'll have to change the APIs of your routines from taking a `char*` to a `std::string&`, but you will be able to modify the string's value like you did the char*.

Comment: Aaaah, thank you, that did the trick. Sorry for posting so much code that you had to slog through.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, you may wish to have another look at your memory management in that code above. Lots of `new` allocations without `delete`s there, so leaking memory.

Comment: Yeah, I realize this fact. I've been mostly worried about making it work since it's a run-once then quit program. I'll be sure to add in some memory cleaning next now that it works. Thanks for pointing it out though.